# Why can't I access a local variable inside a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby file named test.rb

```
ff="ff"
def test
  puts ff
end
```

I execute it, got error:

`` test.rb:3:in `test': undefined local variable or method `ff' for main:Object (NameError) ``

What's the reason for this? Is there any documentation to explain it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason `ff` is inaccessible inside the `test` method definition is simply that methods (created with the `def` keyword) create a new scope. Same with defining classes and modules using the `class` and `module` keywords respectively.

The role of `main` (the top-level object) is almost completely irrelevant to the question of scope in this situation.

Note that, if you DO want your `test` method to have access to locals defined in the definition context, then use the `define_method` (or in your case, the `define_singleton_method` method), see here:

```
ff = "hi"
define_singleton_method("test") { ff }
test #=> "hi"
```

Unlike the `def` keyword, the `define_method` family of methods do not create new scopes but instead close over the current scope, capturing any local variables.

The reason using `@ff` worked in the next example given by @soup, is not that `main` is somehow a "special case" it's just that an ivar defined at top-level is an ivar of `main` and so is accessible to a method invoked on `main`.

What, however, is the relationship of the `test` method to `main`? It is not a method *on* just `main` itself - it is actually a private instance method defined on the  `Object` class. This means that the `test` method would be available (as a private method) to nearly every object in your ruby program. All methods defined at top-level (`main`) are actually defined as private instance methods on the `Object` class.

For more information on the Ruby top-level, see this article: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/

Comment: Thanks for this. I get how main is working now. Cool that `MyObject.new.__send__(:test)` works! (Though maybe not useful).

Re:`Test1Fixed` I thought I did go onto explain that the `@ff` var is a member of the class, hence why it is nil, `Test2` was supposed to explain this by its output ("`will/will NOT output 'instance'`" depending on if you call `test` or `class_test`) but perhaps I wasn't particularly clear. Also if you wrote/started pry, it's pretty cool bro!

Comment: @soup updated the answer to reflect that you did properly explain `@ff`, sorry :) Thx re pry, glad you like it :)

Answer (score 16):

Ruby scope is both simple and complex.

First you have to remember that everything is an object and everything has a scope.

To answer your question directly, `main` is an object and such when you write `def x...` you're defining a method on the object `main`

Observe in pyr/irb:

```
# note the error describes 
[1] pry(main)> main 'main:Object'
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'main' for main:Object
from (pry):1:in '<main>'

# self is the current object, which is main
[2] pry(main)> self
=> main 

# note main is an object of type Object
[3] pry(main)> self.class
=> Object 

# main has methods
[4] pry(main)> self.methods
=> [:to_s, :public, etc etc]
```

So when you write

```
ff = "ff"
def test
    puts ff
end
```

what you're really doing is

```
class main
    ff = "ff"
    def test
        puts ff
    end
end
```

Which doesn't work because `ff` is out of scope. To fix this you have to turn `ff` into an instance variable, so prepend its name with `@`. The following will work:

```
@ff = "ff"
def test
    puts @ff
end

test
```

Note that this seems to be a special case for `main` than regular classes, see below.

If we have our own test class:

```
class Test1
    ff = "ff"
    def test
        puts ff
    end
end

Test1.new.test # undefined variable/method 'ff' error
```

This fails because `ff` is not defined in the correct scope as expect. It is instead scoped to when the parser is executing our class declaration.

So lets try the fix above:

```
class Test1Fixed
    @ff = "ff"
    def test
        puts @ff
    end
end

Test1Fixed.new.test # results in blank line
```

Thats weird.

Lets add this method:

```
def ff?
    puts "ff is: #{@ff.nil? ? "nil" : "not nill"}"
end

Test1Fixed.new.ff? # => ff is: nil
```

Why is @ff nil?

The following might make this more clear:

```
class Test2
    puts "Where am i?"
    @instance = "instance"

    def initialize
        puts "Initalize"
    end

    puts "pants on"

    def test
        puts "This will NOT output 'instance': #{@instance}"
    end

    def self.class_test
        puts "This WILL output 'instance': #{@instance}"
    end
end

puts "Creating new Test2 Object"
t = Test2.new
puts "Calling test on Test2 Object"
t.test

puts "Calling class_test on Test2 Class object" 
Test2.class_test
```

Running this we get the following output:

```
$ ruby scope.rb 
Where am i?
pants on
Creating new Test2 Object
Initalize
Calling test on Test2 Object
This will NOT output 'instance': 
Calling class_test on Test2 Class object
This WILL output 'instance': instance
```

As you can see, the interperter runs over our class declaration in order, just like anywhere else and outputs our `puts` statements. This gets more interesting when we start calling methods. Writing `@instance = ...` is the same as writing `self.instance = ...`, so can you guess where we've defined instance? Yep, on the Test2 class object (not a Test2 object).

This is why when we call `test`, nothing is outputed, because inside `test`, `self` refers to the instanciated `Test2` object, not the `Test2 class object` (which is where we set @instance to be anything!). This is why you setup your instance variables inside `initialize`, where `self` will point to the actual object.

You can see when we define a class method via `self.class_test` and then call that method on the Test2 class object (`Test2.class_test`), we get the expected output, because in that scope, `@instance` was defined.

Hope this made some sense.

The http://rubykoans.com/ scope section may help solidify some of this knowledge.

Comment: No, when you define a method at top-level (main) you're actually defining a private instance method on the `Object` class itself. The only way to define a method on just `main` is to define a method on `main`'s singleton class, a la: `def self.hello; end`

Comment: Actually, re-reading your answer, most of it is completely wrong hehe.

Comment: Could you edit it or point me to where I can learn more. I haven't studied particular topic (main etc, I _have_ studied ruby scopes/objects, though maybe not to the fullest degree), only put together what I knew/thought I knew about ruby objects/scope.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, a name without a sigil always has "local" scope.  Ruby uses lexical scoping, so inside a method, the name always refers to that method only.

The other scopes are global, instance and class.  Here is a good document about them:
 http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Scope

There are a few ways to solve your problem; my favourite would be to pass the thing being printed as an argument:

```
ff = "ff"
def test(ff)
  puts ff
end
```

More likely, you'd be encapsulating whatever you're doing in a class and using an instance variable.

You could also just use a global variable ($ff), but that way madness lies.

Comment: If you just want to share a variable in current file, it is better to use `@a` than `$a`, as it could prevent namespace pollution in some extend.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I access a local variable inside a method in Ruby?

Because it's a *local variable*. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. That's why they are called "local variables", after all.

In this case, you have defined a local variable in the script scope, and thus it is visible in the script scope, and *nowhere else*.

Comment: in many languages i'd think methods are within the scope of the class, so if a variable is local to a class then it's accessible to all methods within that class.. obviously not in the case of ruby though.

Comment: also, you write of script scope, but googling ruby "script scope" isn't coming up with anything. It sounds like a good term though.