# Mysterious error with beginner's ruby code (while loops)

Tags: ruby

So this is my code. I'm learning while loops and not sure why this doesn't work. I'm getting an error.

```
i = 0
numbers = []
def while_var(x)
  while i < #{x}
  print "Entry #{i}: i is now #{i}."
  numbers.push(i)
  puts "The numbers array is now #{numbers}."
  i = i + 1
  puts "variable i just increased by 1. It is now #{i}."
 end

while_var(6)
 puts "Want to see all the entries of the numbers array individually (i.e. not in array format)? Here you go!"

for num in numbers
  puts num
 end

puts "1337"
```

This is my error

```
1.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  print "Entry #{i}: i is now #{i}."
         ^
```

I have no idea what this is all about. Thanks.

EDIT

So I have this revised code

```
def while_var(x)

  i = 0
  numbers = []

  while i < x
    print "Entry #{i}: i is now #{i}."
    numbers.push(i)
    puts "The numbers array is now #{numbers}."
    i = i + 1
    puts "variable i just increased by 1. It is now #{i}."
  end

  puts "next part"

  for num in numbers
    puts num
  end

end


while_var(6)
```

It works when I type it line-by-line into irb, but not when I run the file with ruby. What gives? I'm getting this error:

```
Entry 0: i is now 0.1.rb:8:in `while_var': undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from 1.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

EDIT : Figured it out. All I had to do was change the "print" to "puts" for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fixed code :

```
def while_var(x)
  i = 0
  numbers = []
  while i < x
    print "Entry #{i}: i is now #{i}."
    numbers.push(i)
    puts "The numbers array is now #{numbers}."
    i = i + 1
    puts "variable i just increased by 1. It is now #{i}."
  end
end
```

You did several mistakes :

- You forgot to close the `while` loop.
- You used `#{x}` which is not correct syntax for interpolation,But you don't need interpolation here. make it only x.
- Inside the method two local variables `i` and `numbers` can't be used,as they have created at the top level. So you need to create those variables locally inside the method.

Comment: Would you format it properly? To illustrate importance of formatting in spotting bugs? :)

Comment: @MarekLipka You are most welcome.. please go ahead :)

Comment: @macsplean did you also modify your `while` condition?

Comment: @MarekLipka no ... how would I recommend I do so? Thank you for your help btw!

Comment: @macsplean it should be `while i < x`, just as ArupRakshit wrote.

Comment: now i am getting 1.rb:4:in `while_var': undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object (NameError)
 from 1.rb:13:in `<main>'

Comment: hmm, now the code works up until the for loop, where I get an error regarding an undefined local variable or method 'numbers'. I must say I am rather confused about this issue. I am surprised that I need to define numbers and i within the while_var (I thought they were defined globally in the code I submitted in my question).

Comment: Also check this for further reference why variables defined outside the method cannot be seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389432/ruby-can-not-access-variable-outside-the-method

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to put a $ in front of my variables to make them global.

Comment: @macsplean abusing global variables is anti-pattern. And it's not Ruby-way at all.

Comment: Hey, I've revised my code, and something weird is still happening. Do you mind looking above at my edits and letting me know what you think?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out. All I needed to do was change the "print" to "puts", for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work:

```
def while_var(x)
  i  = 0
  numbers = []

  while i < x
    puts "Entry #{i}: i is now #{i}."

    numbers.push(i)
    puts "The numbers array is now #{numbers}."

    i = i + 1
    puts "variable i just increased by 1. It is now #{i}."
  end

  numbers
end

numbers = while_var(6)
puts "Want to see all the entries of the numbers array individually (i.e. not in array format)? Here you go!"

for num in numbers
  puts num
end
```

I hope it does what you wanted to achieve.

You should use `puts` to print something to console. And move `i` and `numbers` variables to `while_var` method.